# python matplotlib OHLC error

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

The purpose of this code is to plot a csv file which contains 7 columns

```
['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
```

into candlesticks chart OHLC.

I began with parsing the Date Time as single thing, then defining it as index.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

column_names = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
df = pd.read_csv(r"E:\Business\Stocks\AUDUSD60.csv", names=column_names,
                 parse_dates={'DateTime': ['Date', 'Time']},
                 index_col=[0], header=None, low_memory=False)

f1 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 4), (1, 0), rowspan=6, colspan=4, axisbg='#07000d')
candlestick_ohlc(f1, df.values, width=.6, colorup='#53c156', colordown='#ff1717')
f1.xaxis_date()
f1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.ylabel('AUDUSD60')
plt.xlabel('Date Hours:Minutes')
plt.show()
```

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "E:/Tutorial/pan.py", line 16, in <module>
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)

File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 1633, in xticks
    locs = ax.get_xticks()

File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 3029, in get_xticks
    return self.xaxis.get_ticklocs(minor=minor)

File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1272, in get_ticklocs
    return self.major.locator()

File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 1061, in __call__
    self.refresh()

File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 1081, in refresh
    dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()

File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 839, in viewlim_to_dt
    return num2date(vmin, self.tz), num2date(vmax, self.tz)

File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 445, in num2date
    return _from_ordinalf(x, tz)

File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 260, in _from_ordinalf
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix).replace(tzinfo=UTC)

ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
```

Comment: Please read and understand [mcve].

Comment: It would help if you also gave a few lines from your CSV file so your script can be tested.